# Передача нескольких значений из формы

Tags: c#, winforms

Прошу  помочь вот с таким вопросом. У меня в форме ( это форма дочерняя) есть три текст бокса: `tboxCarYear`, `tboxCarModel`, `tboxCarColor`Я хочу отправить эти три данные в главную форму за один раз ( В виде объекта или класса). По отдельности все  получается отправлять.

С# начал изучать недавно, но могу в javascrip-те это выглядело бы так:

```
var ObjCar=new Object(); // создаю новый объект
ObjCar.Model="Mercedes";
ObjCar.Color="blue";
ObjCar.Year=2015;
```

Далее, я отправляю ObjCar и все необходимые данные я получил бы. 
Как такое реализовать в С#?

Comment: из вашего вопроса могу представить, что отношения к Web это не имеет. Но тогда зачем тут в метках javascript?

Comment: Возможно Вам подойдут Анонимные типы https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb397696.aspx

Comment: @Dmitry, мне почему-то кажется, что это для онлайн игры, типо SAMP, MTA, Garry's Mod, где для кода используются своим программы. \Добавил\ Похож на Lua, там код сильно на JS помож.

Answer (score 2):

Создайте класс `CarInfo`:

```
public class CarInfo
{
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

Создавайте экземпляр и передавайте его в форму:

```
var carInfo = new CarInfo()
{
    Model = tboxCarModel.Text,
    Color = tboxCarColor,
    Year = Convert.ToInt32(tboxCarYear.Text)
};
```

Это будет более [типизировано и наглядно](https://refactoring.guru/ru/introduce-parameter-object), нежели использование анонимных классов и динамиков:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var o = new { Model = "123" };
    Foo(o);
}

static void Foo(dynamic obj)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Model);
}
```